# HTML 5 front end with C++ library

Tags: c++, html, ftp

I am planning to develop a file transfer application.
I have a file transfer library which works on all platforms such as iOS, win, mac etc.
I am planning to write a HTML based GUI so that it works on all platforms.
How can HTML5 GUI interact with C++ library?

Comment: Is your application going to upload files via HTTP? Or?

Comment: NOTE: You can get the web toolkit library for C++.
http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

Comment: @ jweyrich , the applicatin will upload files only by FTP using CURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so much about HTML5 interacting with C++, rather keeping to the HTTP specs.

With HTTP, code is sent via the standard stream. In C++, you can send HTML with:

```
cout << "html code here";
```

POST data comes through standard input stream:

```
cin >> POST_DATA;
```

And get data comes through the QUERY_STRING environmental variable. (I don't know how to do that...)